# Is it possible to customize the subject of an email-ext generated email based on the build that finished

Tags: templates, jenkins, email-ext

I know you can use a few tokens to customize the subject of the email, but I am looking for something a little more dynamic. I was hoping I could set an environment variable or write to a file somewhere from my build script, and have email-ext use that when formatting its email subject.

Is there anything available that might allow this?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the email subject using a pre-send groovy script as well.

For example, the following script checks for certain conditions and prepends some text on the subject line:

```
boolean isClaimed = false;
build.actions.each { action ->
   if(action.class.name == "hudson.plugins.claim.ClaimBuildAction" 
      && action.isClaimed()) {
       isClaimed = true;
       hudson.model.User user = hudson.model.User.get(action.getClaimedBy()); 
       logger.println("[addClaimerOrCulprits.groovy] Build is claimed by " + user);
       logger.println("[addClaimerOrCulprits.groovy] Sending email to claimer");
       address = user.getProperty(hudson.tasks.Mailer.UserProperty).getAddress() ; 
       msg.addRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, address ); 
       msg.setSubject("Attn " + action.getClaimedBy() + ": " + msg.getSubject());
   }
}
```